# SQL Query With In Operator returns data mentioned in IN clause, how to find that data doesnot exists for one param mentioned in IN

Tags: sql, operators

SQL Query With In Operator returns data mentioned in IN clause, how to find that data doesnot exists for one param mentioned in IN

Example :

```
Select EmpName from Salary Where EmpID In (1,2,3,4,100)
```

Now there is no record by Id 100 in table but result does not reflect this,

Any Clue

Comment: What should be the outcome of this query?

Comment: what do you mean by "result does not reflect this"?

The `IN` keyword is basically a replacement for an `OR` clause.

So it is searching for records `WHERE EmpID = 1 OR EmpID = 2 OR`... etc.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: OP wants to see that 1 employee was not found from that list. The question is in what way that should be displayed.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably create a temporary table and do a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join to then always select the `EmpID` from my temp table and either have `NULL` or `EmpName` from `Salary` displayed.

you would then end up with a query like: -

```
SELECT
    T.EmpId,
    S.EmpName
FROM
   Salary S
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   TempTable T
ON
   T.EmpID = EmpID
```

Comment: hmmm thanks would solve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Select EmpName 
from Salary 
Where EmpID In (1,2,3,4,100)
```

is equivalent to

```
Select EmpName 
from Salary 
Where EmpID = 1
  OR EmpID = 2
  OR EmpID = 3
  OR EmpID = 4
  OR EmpID = 100
```

And will return all the rows where the where condition is true.

It will not return a row with EmpID=100, if there is no such row...

This is a messy way of getting what you want achieved, in MySQL

```
select ids_to_get.id, EmpName from
from 
(select 1 id
union all
select 2 id
union all
select 3 id
union all
select 4 id
union all
select 100 id) ids_to_get
left join Salary on ids_to_get.id = Salary.EmpID
```

This will return the ids in one column, and the eployee names in the other. if there is no such employee, it will have NULL as the name. (this is what the LEFT JOIN does)

However, this is **ugly**. Indeed, very ugly, not scalable, and generally something to avoid. I'd advise not to use such a construct... If there is no way to create a temp table, and the IDs don't come from another query, I'd advise to check it in the application rather than use this union-ed structure.